# Configure MTU size on Azure PaaS

Tags: wcf, azure, networking, tcp, azure-web-roles

We're running a WCF based API on Windows Azure Web Roles in North Europe. Recently we have had issues with very unstable connections to a client running on AWS US East. A wireshark dump from our Azure instance showed that TCP packets was lost somewhere along the path with several TCP retransmission happening from our Azure instances.

AWS excellent support helped us nail down that this was probably being caused due to the Azure Instances use of Jumbo Frames with fragment sizes > 1500 bytes and the path MTU discovery not working properly. A note is that Usually the connections would get stuck already in the TLS handshake (our API runs over HTTPS) as the TLS Hello package would be around 5000 bytes.

My question is, what is the recommended way to configure the MTU size on Azure PaaS? Running an netsh command on the instances would not be persistent when the cloud fabric relocate instances etc.

Also, have anyone experienced similar issues? I'm worried about degraded network performance to other cloud resources (SQL Azure, Blob Storage, Service Bus) when lowering the MTU from the default.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set your MTU config on a start-up task?
That would run again on every start/reboot
You can also check if the role wasn't moved, and ignore the script...

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common/#detect-that-your-task-has-already-run

Jumbo Frames are not enabled by default, so you can run a PS script on start, and manually enable it.

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -DisplayName "Jumbo Packet" | Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty –RegistryValue "9014"
```

I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a try! I'm wondering about your comment on not enabled by default though. It's definitely not something we have enabled - as a test, we did a completely clean cloud project with a test WCF service with a HTTPS endpoint, and clearly see packets with size > 1500 bytes and DontFragment flag set. I guess we should be enable to reverse your PS script to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Azure instances wasn't really sending Jumbo Frames. The packages captured by Wireshark just indicates this because of [TCP large Segment Offload](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/24699/tcp-packet-length-was-much-greater-than-mtu). After disabling this, Wireshark indicates properly formatted TCP packets. Our hunt for the lost packages between Azure and AWS continues.

Answer (score 0):

I recently speak with someone working at Microsoft and the MTU recommanded is 1400 (in France Central) because of the SDN (VXLAN and may be other thing). The documentation is not the same between countries, and you have to check that.

I've got did a curl with a pdf file into my payload, and I could still have a 504 Gateway Time-out.
With the 1400 MTU, the call was OK with a 200.

I hope this could help you.